# Why can't Mathematica solve this equation numerically?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have a rather nasty-looking function `Ratio`, given by,

```
f[n_, t_] = 
  Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && 0 < t < Pi/2, 
   Integrate[Cos[x]^n, {x, Pi/2 - t, Pi/2}]];
cn[n_] = Pi^(n/2)/Gamma[n/2 + 1]; 
g[n_, t_] = cn[n - 1]*(Sin[(t)]^(n - 1)*Cos[(t)]/n + f[n, t]);
Ratio[n_, t_] = FullSimplify[g[n^2, t]/cn[n^2]]
```

Given values `p_n` that fall in the range from $0$ to $1/4$, I wish to solve `Ratio[n,t]==p_n` for values of `t` in the range from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

But when I run

```
Assuming[0 < t < Pi/2, NSolve[Ratio[2, t] == 0.250277, t, Reals]]
```

Mathematica doesn't seem to ever arrive at an answer. The `Ratio`-function looks normal enough and there should exist solutions in the given intervals:

[image]

What goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try `FindRoot` instead. `NSolve` is mainly for polynomial equations and equations involving some small number of elementary functions.

Comment: @march Thanks, that worked beautifully! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Or should I delete this question (as it is probably a duplicate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `NSolve` about the bounds explicitly:

```
NSolve[Ratio[2, t] == 0.250277 && 0 < t < Pi/2, t, Reals]
(* {{t -> 1.15546}} *)
```

Comment: Can I, in general, simply add my list of assumptions after the equality, or is this only valid for the range of the variable which is being solved for?

Comment: @Lovsovs: See under "Details" in the [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) documentation for the kinds of things you can put there; there are a lot of possibilities.